# How to get behavior like a radio button group so only one item can be selected

Tags: c#

I made a user control and placed it in a panel. The user control has its own mouse click event that changes color. If I click on a control on the panel, I want the other controls to be deselected. Like radio buttons. How can I do that?

Here is a picture of my panel. There is both of two user controls is selected.

[image: 1]

```
public partial class list : UserControl
{
    void chgtxt(Label lbl, string s)
    {
        lbl.Text = s;
    }

    public list()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void panel1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        chgtxt(label1, "Changed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Really, you are not asking how to make a list panel, but how to get behavior like a radio button group so only one item can be selected. You should update your title.

Comment: Thanks @ScottChamberlain. Title updated.

Comment: You don't need the "in C#", questions have tags allready you don't need to put them in the title too.

Comment: I am new in C# programming and also new in Stackoverflow. Thanks for your valuable help. @ScottChamberlain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enumerate the panel's children and deselect the ones that aren't the current control:

```
foreach (list listControl in Parent.Controls.Cast<Control>().OfType<list>())
{
    if (list != this)
    {
        list.Deselect();
    }
}
```

Then you just have to create a `Deselect()` method on your control:

```
public void Deselect()
{
    // Do whatever to show this control as deselected.
}
```

Comment: This is a great idea but I think you are a little confused about the hierarchy of items. `this` is a item that is sitting inside some kind of listbox or similar. so really what the op would use is `foreach (list listControl in Parent.Controls.Cast<Control>.OfType<list>())`

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [itsme86's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38797279/80274), you need to look at the parent control your control is part of and deselect the other items in the list.

```
public partial class list : UserControl
{
    void chgtxt(Label lbl, string s)
    {
        lbl.Text = s;
    }

    public list()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void panel1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        chgtxt(label1, "Changed");

        if(this.Parent != null)
        {    
            foreach (list listControl in this.Parent.Controls.Cast<Control>().OfType<list>())
            {
                if (listControl != this)
                {
                    listControl.Deselect();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Deselect()
    {
        // Do whatever to show this control as deselected.
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I got this error.
EnumerableRowCollectionExtensions.Cast<TResult>(EnumerableRowCollection)' is a method, which is not valid in the given context

Comment: Oops, I forgot a set of () after `Cast<Control>`

Comment: 'using System.Linq;' inserted and .NET version is newer. But not working.

Comment: Refresh the page and try the new code again, I had a few mistakes.

Comment: Yes. It's working. :D Many thanks. I don't know much about enumeration. Would you please give me some resource link?

Comment: Resource on what? This is just basic winforms programming.